# Heading numbering in paragraph numbering

Tags: microsoft-word, numbering

How can I get the numbering in the following style?

```
1.0 Heading 1
1.1 Paragraph 1 of Heading 1
1.2 Paragraph 2 of Heading 1
1.3 Paragraph 3 of Heading 1
1.1 Heading 2
1.1.1 Paragraph 1 of Heading 2
1.1.2 Paragraph 2 of Heading 2
1.1.3 Paragraph 3 of Heading 2

2.0 Heading 1
2.1 Paragraph 1 of Heading 1
2.2 Paragraph 2 of Heading 1
2.3 Paragraph 3 of Heading 1
2.1 Heading 2
2.1.1 Paragraph 1 of Heading 2
2.1.2 Paragraph 2 of Heading 2
2.1.3 Paragraph 3 of Heading 2
```

Comment: In what program?

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar: based upon his tagging: "word". But you are right, this information belongs explicitly into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the question was: How can I get the following style in `Microsoft Word`?

```
1.0 Heading 1
1.1 Paragraph 1 of Heading 1
1.2 Paragraph 2 of Heading 1
1.3 Paragraph 3 of Heading 1
1.1 Heading 2
1.1.1 Paragraph 1 of Heading 2
1.1.2 Paragraph 2 of Heading 2
1.1.3 Paragraph 3 of Heading 2
```

So the real issue is that `Heading 2` is not at the same level as `Heading 1`. Otherwise you could use the nested list style:

[image]