# Use Chapter Numbering as part of paragraph numbering

Tags: libreoffice-writer, numbering

I always use "Chapter Numbering" (formerly known as "outline numbering") for my Heading styles in Libre Office Writer, with multiple heading hierarchies. Most paragraphs are not numbered, but on some particular sections in the "Heading 1" level, I will need to number the paragraphs displaying the 2 hierarchy levels. This looks like a good use case for numbered list, but
how can I use the "chapter numbering" as part of the list style without using a heading style, and consequently messing the other levels of "Chapter Numbering". Even if I were numbering all paragraphs, I don't know how to do it.

Example:

**1** Section ONE

***1.1** sub-Section One*

Text of sub-Section One. Not all sections have a subsection.

***1.2** sub-Section Two*

Text of sub-Section Two

**2** Section TWO

2.1 This is a paragraph, not a sub-section, so it cannot be the same style as sub-section One heading, but it will display a number in the same hierarchic  level (2.1). I could change the list style manually to start at "2" in the first level, have no items in first level and start at level 2, but this is a cheat that will get me in trouble at Section FOUR.

2.2 Section three has no numbered paragraphs.

**3** Section THREE

Text of Section THREE, not numbered.

**4** Section FOUR

4.1 Now the paragraphs are numbered again. And it should start in number 4.1 because it is the first paragraph of the 4th section. But I can't just reuse the list style of section 2, because that would start on 2.3 (or maybe 3.1.

4.2 If I leave an invisible level 1 item on a blank line). If I tell the numbering style to start at 4, this messes up section 2.

4.3 There is no option to "Start level on previous levels at Current Heading number"

Obs: [There is a related question](https://superuser.com/questions/159353/heading-numbering-in-paragraph-numbering), although in the context of MS Word instead of Libre. There was no helpful answer, and the problem does not seem to be the same.